# wordpress pll__ error after moving to another folder

Tags: wordpress

Im not really a wordpress expert and that's why I'm here.
I moved a perfectly working website from one folder to another and gave it another domain name. However the site got broken, Fatal error: Call to undefined function pll__().

Any wordpress experts out there? Any advice appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Heh the actual plugin was missing for some reason.. all sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

> You have an outdated PolyLang plugin, as a result of this you cannot update WordPress.
> Updating wordpress, you get an error, then in the wp-setting.php file before do_action( 'plugins_loaded' ); write require( ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/polylang-pro/include/api.php' ); path to the polylang API, check it.
> 2. Try to update again, the update process will start and the error will come out again. Remove require( ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/polylang-pro/include/api.php' ); save, and continue updating again, and so on 2 times until the database is updated.
> 3. After that remove require( ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/polylang-pro/include/api.php' ); and update the PolyLang plugin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was a bit different, with an existing WordPress project and a custom theme, I had to **complete the initial setup** of Polylang first, otherwise the home page remains with the same error. no plugin update was required.